# How to avoid class name conflict with a package "loaded via a namespace (and not attached)" (qdap & openssl)

Tags: r, qdap

Using the `qdap::polarity()` function can sometimes run into the error:

> Error in derive_pubkey(key) : 
>     RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'list'

I'm fairly certain this is due `qdap`'s `key` class conflicting with the `openssl` package's `key` class (since `derive_pubkey()` from `openssl` is referenced in the error msg).

The error happens when `openssl` appears in the `loaded via a namespace (and not attached):` section of `sessionInfo()`, and it seems to throw off method dispatch for the key class and cause the error.

I've only been able to fix the error by restarting my R session.  Is there a way to remove `openssl`'s footprint from the session to fix this issue?  Or is there another way to avoid this issue without restarting R?

#### recreation of error

```
> successful      <- qdap::polarity("testing")
> load_openssl_ns <- body(openssl:::print.key)
> fails           <- qdap::polarity("testing")
Error in derive_pubkey(key) : 
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'list'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a dirty fix run

```
`[[.qdap_hash` <- `[[.data.frame`
```

Checking...

```
> qdap::polarity("test")
  all total.sentences total.words ave.polarity sd.polarity stan.mean.polarity
1 all               1           1            0          NA                 NA
> library(openssl)
Warning message:
package ‘openssl’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
> qdap::polarity("test")
Error in derive_pubkey(key) : 
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'list'
> `[[.qdap_hash` <- `[[.data.frame`
> qdap::polarity("test")
  all total.sentences total.words ave.polarity sd.polarity stan.mean.polarity
1 all               1           1            0          NA                 NA
>
```

The offending line in `polarity` is `words <- c(posneg, alter[[1]])`

The object `alter` gets created with `alter_env` which creates an object which has classes "qdap_hash", "key", ...

qdap_hash doesn't have it's own '[[' method so it checks to see if key has a '[[' method which it typically doesn't. Once openssl gets loaded there is a [[ method for key so it uses that and gives the error since it isn't in the form expected.  If we define our own method for qdap_hash that gets called before even attempting to use `[[.key` so we bypass the issue.  The author of qdap has been informed of the issue and the possible fix.

Comment: thanks for the find.  I have added this to the export of qdapTools which will fix for all other packages that rely on qdapTools.  The dev version of qdapTools can be installed with: `if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman"); p_load_current_gh('trinker/qdapTools')`

Comment: @TylerRinker Any ideas when your next push to CRAN will be for qdap?